# How do I uninstall Ubuntu and go back to what I had before I installed it?

Tags: uninstall

I bought the book " The art of exploitation 2nd edition" and it came with the disk that I loaded onto my computer. I installed it not knowing that I would have this trouble booting windows and all my files back up to what I had previously. Can someone please help??

Comment: From what I see on Amazon about this book, it should have "LiveCD" that works without installing. You should know that installing an OS means changing boot sectors and if you had your Windows on this same drive, you will need to fix that later for dual-boot (option for that during install not always works properly). Unless you have formatted the drive... in such case I would completely discourage playing a "hacker" xD

Comment: I know that the cd works without installing but the install option was 1 of two programs on the desktop when booted up and it noted that you would be able to save all your work etc if you installed and it didnt take but a few min to do so.. Im new to most of this so are there any solutions?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming from your silence, that you don't want to admit to a folly, so I'm deleting unnanswered comments, doing a summarization and hopefully closing the case, which is one of those cases of:

> **Don't try this at home, kids!** (or pre-learn how to do it safely)

---

That "LiveCD" from that peculiar "*The art of exploitation*" book actually is fully functional in "live" usage and does not require any installations. They are even clearly stating that in f.e. Amazon's description (and presumably multiple times in that book itself):

> The included LiveCD provides a complete Linux programming and debugging environment - all without modifying your current operating system.

Why would you even want to install that permanently if you just started learning? Personally I would even disconnect all of my media and networks before booting any "hacker's" compilations on any of my machines!

You have performed Ubuntu 7.04 installation. I know, because out of extreme curiousity I tried it myself on one my virtual M$'s that had volunteered for such experiment after backup-copying it's entire virtual drive.

Everything looks orderly in that installation. It gives 3 options for partitioning:

1. resize (default, attempt to keep old system & stuff alive)
2. use entire disk (would completely crush your status quo)
3. manual (you probably wouldn't even make it through that one)

It even has a normal warning "You cannot undo this operation". I performed a "resize" and it normally installed itself and I can now dual-boot without having need to fix anything (like specially configured boot for my "Crazy 8"). Both systems works fine, no files lost and actually no problems at all (at least noticable ones).

Did you perhaps choose that second, nuclear method? The only rescue after that involves performing "data recovery" using specialized not-so-easy-to-use software or paying large amount of money to some even more specialized entity that would do that for you (or asking a bona-fide hacker-friend for a favour). And after such retrieval-attemp, you would get your data mostly fragmented, unusable or even non-existing at all (overwritten). If you have a large drive, then chances for restoring more complete files are higher.

If you however choose that other, the only sane method for such cases as yours, I believe that it's still possible to un-do it by removing Linux's partition & extending your M$ one (f.e. by using some other live Linux system). Most trouble would give you restoring original Windows's boot manager (BOOTMGR). I don't even know if that's achievable... easier to just live with GRUB from now on (naturally after properly re-configuring it).

Sorry to say that, but you have "exploited yourself"! (and it's as hilarious as that sounds)

For a finish, I'll quote you from my first comment:

> ... I would completely discourage playing a "hacker" xD

Answer (score 0):

Insert the "exploitation" livecd, boot it up to desktop, open GParted, erase ext partition and swap partition. Reboot. Insert the Windows instalation cd and choose Repair Windows option. Wait for the process to finish.  Reboot again. Ta da!